# Python 3.10 Popen behavior after update from 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-2.x

I am updating some old python scripts from 2.7 to 3.10 and can't figure out the behavior of one function.

```
def export_from_source(self):
    self.dt_start = datetime.now()
    p = subprocess.Popen(self.esbadmin_cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout=self.logs.export_log, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    p.stdin.write(self.export_cmd)
    self.export_process = p
```

This function when executed in 2.7 normally would execute the  `esbadmin_cmd.bat`, it would do it's thing, and you would see the results populate in the working directory - it generates files we use as part of our deployment process.

When running it using 3.10 however, in an ipython session, throws no errors and seems to work as intended, but the process of creating the files in the directory doesn't happen until I type `exit()`, exiting the ipython session.

Is there something in this function that has changed from 2.7-3.10 that would be causing this behavior?

Comment: The use of spaces in between equals signs, variables, and commas tends to make code more readable. I recommend doing this.

Comment: If you never flush or close `p.stdin`, you're depending on some unspecified behavior. I'd strongly suggest `p.stdin.close()` after the write is complete.

Comment: Beyond that, are you ever actually checking the exit status of `self.export_process`?

Comment: @wjandrea But OP specifically said, [tag:python3.10] & [tag:python2.7]?

Comment: *This function when executed in 2.7 normally would [...]* - was that ipython too?

Comment: @imxitiz Yeah, but for the sake of tags, that's probably unnecessarily precise. Version-specific tags should only be used for questions *specific* to that version, so here, unless OP's tried other versions of 2.x and 3.x and wasn't able to reproduce the same difference in behaviour, the minor version number is moot. That said, this could easily be something that's changed in the 3.x lineage, but IDK where. **Edit**: On the other hand, after a solution is found, if it turns out to be minor-version-specific, we could add the tag then.

Comment: In this case @CharlesDuffy had the solution. `p.stdin.close()` solved the problem. Now I'm not sure why this code would work in 2.7 but need to have `p.stdin.close()` in 3.x.

Comment: @iNeedScissors61, one of the things about unspecified behavior is that you end up with details that are implementation-defined and outside the scope of the language spec. I don't tend to consider worrying about the "why"s of undefined behavior changing as worthwhile; _any_ reliance on UB is a bug, even in versions when that bug isn't immediately manifesting itself, because it opens you up to things breaking by surprise in the future (as happened here). Know your language spec and write code that relies only on things that are explicitly specified, and you're on much more solid ground.

Comment: (Granted, it's more library spec than language spec here -- with respect to FIFO buffering settings used while honoring `subprocess.PIPE` having been indeterminate)